# Ruby-On-Rails Internal Server Error, code 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an "Internal Server Error" (500) from the code of the "[Getting Started](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form)" guide of ruby on rails. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but in the paragraph [5.2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form) the error appears as I reload the page. I copied and pasted the HTML code, but can't find any problem within the code.
The development.log doesn't say more than that.

Is there any other log available? 
Does someone have an idea what exactly goes wrong?

**// EDIT 1:**

```
Started GET "/articles/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-28 18:39:25 +0100
Processing by ArticlesController#new as HTML
  Rendered articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (33.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

That's all I got ...

**// EDIT 2:**

Content of articles/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please add the error stacktrace in the question.

Comment: what does the error says? or what is in the server logs?

Comment: Check `log/development.log` where the actual error is expressed.

Comment: I add the log, but like I said, it is only the last line which tells the error. More information is not there ...

Comment: Can you post the `articles/new.html.erb` file contents. I guess there is some problem with variables not defined in the controller?

Comment: Are you running in development mode? Normally an exception stacktrace is logged on internal server error. If so, you might not have `config.log_level` set as `:debug`.

Comment: @Reghav Raman: The content is added to the second edit.

Comment: @3limin4t0r: The log_level is already set to debug.

Comment: The response code 500 says, that there is normally something wrong on the scripting side. means, that the code might be corrupted. I have the feeling, that the problem appears because of the from_with tag, but I'm not sure. If I replace the complete code by a simple <h1>Test</h1>, then it is working.